# exponential equation quick-select algorithm

Tags: exponential-function, recursive-algorithms

i'm trying to proof that quickSelect algorithm RunTime complexity is: Theta(n)

With Akra-Buzzi method.

So i need to Solve this recursive function: T(n) = T(n/5) + T(7n/10) + n

i need to find p, such that: (1/5)^p + (7/10)^p = 1.

and i cant solve this exponential equation :/

Comment: Numerical methods give $p \approx 0.83$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(p)=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^p+\left(\frac{7}{10}\right)^p-1$$ For simplicity of further notations, let $a=\frac{1}{5}$ and $b=\frac{7}{10}$.

We have $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=-\frac{1}{10}$; so the solution is a bit smaller than $1$. Just start Newton method with $p_0=1$ and you will have as iterates
$$p_{n+1}=p_n-\frac{f(p_n)}{f'(p_n)}=p_n-\frac{a^{p_n}+b^{p_n}-1 }{a^p \log (a)+b^p \log (b) }$$ This would give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & p_n \\
 0 & 1.000000 \\
 1 & 0.825040 \\
 2 & 0.839659 \\
 3 & 0.839780
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. just now i notice ,that i need to proof the existance of p. and intermediate value theorem is enough : f(0) = 1 >  and f(1) = -0.1 < 0  => exist  0<p<1 such that: f(p)=0  => (1/5)^p + (7/10)^p - 1 = 0 => (1/5)^p + (7/10)^p = 1 QED.

Comment: @GolanArbiv. You are welcome ! What you wrote in comments is correct. Cheers :-)